Can any one prove this that (dy/dx)•(dx/dy)= 1 but for. Y=sinx
If $f(x) = \sin x$ then $dy/dx = \cos x$ and $dx/dy = d(\sin^{-1}y)/dy$.
So, $dy/dx =\cos x$ where $dx/dy = 1/\sqrt{1-x²}$ not $1/\cos x$. Hence, $dy/dx\neq 1/(dx/dy)$. What has gone wrong here?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

No, $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}.$ Now everything is fine.

By $\sin^{-1}$, do you mean $\arcsin$?

Have you assumed that $x\in\left(\frac{-\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right)$? Because then only $\sin^{-1}\sin x=x$.

You're not quite right when you say that $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = 1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$. In fact, we have $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = 1/\sqrt{1-y^2}$. If you then sub in $y=\sin x$, you find that $$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos^2 x}} = \frac{1}{\cos x},$$ as expected.

Does this require $\cos x >0$?

No, because $\cos^2x$ is always non-negative.

It does, because you have $\sqrt{\cos^2 x} = \cos x$ which is only true if $\cos x \geq 0$.

It seems that the OP has assumed $x\in\left[\frac{-\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right]\implies\cos x\ge0$

@MathGuy The OP assumed $x \in \left( -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$, since only there $\sin x$ and $\sin^{-1} y$ are mutually inverse differentiable functions.

@Adayah yes, sorry for the mistake and thanks for pointing it out.
